# Use gnuplot to plot sqlite database

Tags: linux, database, sqlite, ubuntu, gnuplot

I have a sqlite database that contains basic weather information in the following format:

```
temp1 temp2 pressure humidity
22    23    1024     40
24    25    1027     45
25    26    1020     62
18    15    1019     80
```

how can I plot this data using `gnuplot`? Do I have to re-arrange the data before being able to plot it?

Comment: Yes, you can plot this data with gnuplot. But *how* do you want your plot to look like? Are the rows for different days? Did you make any attempt yourself?

Comment: I would like to have temp1,temp2,pressure and humidity in one plot with a different color for each graph. I tried some basic plotting with gnuplot, but I don't have a clue how to connect my sql database to gnuplot. EDIT: Every row represents one minute.

Comment: You can extract the data from your sqlite db on-the-fly, like with `plot '< sqlite3 myfile.db3 "SELECT temp1, temp2, pressure, humidity FROM myTable;"' using 0:1 title 'temp1', '' using 0:2 title 'temp2'` etc. I'm not sure about the exact syntax, but something like this should work.

Comment: Thank you very much! The output is working and looking good so far. If you don't mind would you like to tell me where I can find the documentation for the sqlite3 command in gnuplot, because I found it nowhere.

Comment: The `sqlite3` command is a commandline tool, you'll probably get some information with `man sqlite3`.  The `<` tells gnuplot to invoke a shell and read the data which should be plotted from the output which this call produces.

Comment: Okay "that simple"... Like using the shell itself... One more question, whats the best way to smooth data point without completely manipulating their "real value". I tried plot [...] with line smooth ... but none of these were satisfying.

Comment: Try using `smooth cspline` because that keeps the original values, and does some interpolation only between the points.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To extract the data from your sqlite database, you can use the `sqlite3` command line tool to extract the data on-the-fly. This is done with gnuplot by using a `<` which spawns a shell and uses the output of the given shell commands for plotting.

```
plot '< sqlite3 myfile.db3 "SELECT temp1, temp2, pressure, humidity FROM myTable;"' using 0:1 title 'temp1', \
     '' using 0:2 title 'temp2'
```

This would extract all four fields for each plot (`''` repeats the previous file name / shell command). You could also use function to format the shell command:

```
SqliteField(f) = '< sqlite3 myfile.db3 "SELECT '.f.' from myTable;"'
fields = 'temp1 temp2 pressure humidity'
plot for [f in fields] SqliteField(f) using 0:1 title f
```