# Plot sqlite3 data with gnuplot

Tags: sqlite, gnuplot

I have an sqlite3 db file with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE data(
  Time INT,
  FirstVal INT,
  SecondVal INT
);
```

I need to plot the data in the db using gnuplot so that my x axis corresponds to the Time column, while my y axis should be FirstVal / SecondVal.

Thanks.

Comment: Read the data from the DB, and tell gnuplot to plot it. Everything is described in the respective documentation. What is the problem?

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24994565/2604213

Comment: Then, to plot he ratio, the gnuplot plot line sho uld be something like: `plot '< sqlcommand' using 1:($2/$3) with lines` (replace `sqlcommand` with something meaningful)