# importing sqlite database to gnuplot

Tags: sqlite, gnuplot

This question has partially been answer in this post: [Gnuplot to plot SQlite db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993508/use-gnuplot-to-plot-sqlite-database) but the answer given doesn't quite work for applications.

I have a code reading UDP gps data and storing into sqlite db as time,lat,long ie
`id|time|lat|long
1|083204.69|7216.070578|15328.389869
2|083211.69|7216.075284|15328.423265
3|083214.69|7216.077313|15328.437593`

when I try to run `plot '< sqlite3 /home/usr/sqlite/db/gpsdata.db "SELECT id, lat, long FROM gps;"' using 1:2 title "latitude", '' using 1:3 title "longitude"` I get errors saying `x range is invalid` and `warning: Skipping data file with no valid points`

I can load these individually with
`SqliteField(f) = '< sqlite3 /home/cts/sqlite/db/gpsdata.db "SELECT '.f.' FROM gps;"'
fields = 'time lat long'
plot for [f in fields] SqliteField(f) using 0:1 title f`
but if I want to make the x axis time and not a count variable (i.e. not 0:1 but 1:2) it seems like its not reading the sqlite db properly.

I'd greatly appreciate the help and hope this isn't considered a replicate question.

Comment: Latitude normally varies between -90 and +90, with longitude varying between -180 and +180 so your values look odd.

Comment: @MarkSetchell true but doesn't make a difference in this case. the ship is primarily only ever located in the Beaufort sea so I'm not worried about the N and W identifiers (or -ve values that the W and S would identify)

Answer (score 0):

It was a pretty obvious answer when I found it:

in gnuplot (or in your .conf file if you're calling gnuplot from a program)
you need

`set datafile separator "|"`

because sqlite db's are pipe-separated.